# Is there a way to create a custom view for a Marker in TeeChart

Tags: .net, teechart

At the moment we are limited on what to show in a Marker (text, text/value, text/percentage, ...). I want to show a Marker created with a custom view. For example, first line BIG text, second line a formatted value as currency, third line a right align suffix text. How can I do this?
Is there a way to create an annotation for example and connect the Callouts?
I am using this in both Monotouch as in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Annotation* tools with *Shape.TextFormat* set to HTML and use HTML code for annotation's text. Actually, I found this doesn't work so I added the defect to bugzilla ([ID980](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=980)). The only alternative I can think of for now is derving your own class from Annotation tool that supports HTML text.

You'll find examples on setting Annotation tool positions and callout at *All Features\Welcome !\Tools\Annotation* in the features demo, available at TeeChart's program group.